# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msgpack', but msgpack is already installed

Tags: python, import, module, msgpack

I'm on Windows using PowerShell and I'm trying to run a python script that calls another script that imports msgpack. My msgpack version is 1.0.2.

```
> python3 .\testing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\<path>\testing.py", line 1, in <module>
    import b0RemoteApi
  File "C:\<path>\b0RemoteApi.py", line 7, in <module>
    import msgpack
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msgpack'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. For anyone else who had this problem, I had two versions of Python installed, 3.8 and 3.9. msgpack was installed in the 3.8 directory and PowerShell was using Python 3.9, so I uninstalled the older version and reinstalled msgpack.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I was using two different versions of python somehow because I had different anaconda environments. I removed one of them I it started working again.